# find Limit $a_n= \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

show sequence $a_n= \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}$
converges to log2

my attempt:

1. sequence $a_n$ is monotonic increasing
2. 0<$a_n$<1/2

how to find limit?

Comment: Oh come on, this must be the duplicate of three duplicates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac 1 {n+i}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac 1 n\frac  1 {1+\dfrac in}=\int_0^1\frac 1 {1+x}dx=\ln(1+1)-\ln(1+0)=\ln(2)$$
*(Riemann sum)*

Comment: +1, but  there should be a limit as $n \to \infty$ instead of the sum going to infinity. The sum goes fom $i=1$ to $i=n$

Comment: @6005 Fixed, thank you!

Comment: ya i was hoping there would be some other way. riemann sum cannot be used to compute limit of sequence$ a_n=1+1/2+1/3...+1/n−log(n+1)$

Comment: @ketan Then why not use the harmonic number $H_n$ that was already mentioned by @MichaelGaluza? But I suppose this becomes a slightly different question than the one you asked.

Comment: @ketan $a_n=1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n - \log(n+1)=H_n -\log(n+1)=\log(n)+\gamma + \epsilon_n-\log(n+1)=\log(n/(n+1))+\gamma +\epsilon _n$

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
\log(2)
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}k\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\vphantom{\sum_{k=1}^n}\right.\overbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k}^{\substack{\text{sum of all}\\\text{terms}}}-2\overbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}}^{\substack{\text{sum of even}\\\text{terms}}}\left.\vphantom{\sum_{k=1}^n}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right)\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice overbrace. Is there a corresponding underbrace command or somethings similar?

Comment: Yep. It is `\underbrace` :-) Then you use subscripts instead of superscripts.

Answer (score 3):

Here is classical proof of it. Let $H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$. It's well-known that
$$
H_n = \ln n + \gamma + \epsilon_n,
$$
where $\gamma$ is [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), $\epsilon_n\to 0$. So,
$$
a_n = H_{2n}-H_{n} = \ln 2 + \epsilon_{2n} - \epsilon_n \to \ln2.
$$

Comment: what is $\epsilon_n$? is it always zero?

Comment: @ketan, no. It's sequence which tends to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, $$a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+\ldots +\frac{1}{n+n}$$ 
$$=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+r}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)}$$$$=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{r}{n}}$$
Now, let $\frac{r}{n}=x\implies \frac{1}{n}=dx\to 0$  $$\text{upper limit of x}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n}=1$$
$$\text{lower limit of x}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$ Hence, using integration we get $$a_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}$$ $$=\left[\ln (1+x)\right]_{0}^{1}$$ $$=\left[\ln 2-\ln 1\right]=\ln 2$$